# Знаки препинания при построении предложения

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Вот такое предложение:
*Не надо так делать, повторяю тебе в сотый раз, так делать нельзя.*
Объясните, пожалуйста, знаки препинания.

Answer (score 2):

***Не надо так делать! Повторяю тебе в сотый раз: так делать нельзя.(!)***

Поделите  предложение на два отдельных. Первое предложение по значению близко к побудительному с восклицательной интонацией, поэтому его завершаем восклицательным знаком.

Второе  предложение сложное бессоюзное, ставим двоеточие, так как вторая часть дополняет первую: *повторяю ЧТО?* В конце предложения точка или восклицательный знак. Прямую речь здесь можно не оформлять.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего в предложении не меняем:

Не надо так делать,  **повторяю тебе в сотый раз**, так делать нельзя.

1) Повторяю тебе в сотый раз, сколько раз тебе повторять  и т.д. — эти предложения используются в функции вводных (обращение к собеседнику с целью привлечения внимания к сказанному) и выделяются запятыми (реже тире).

— Дед, **я тебе в сотый раз говорю**, ты не пройдешь! [Александр Снегирев. 2012]

– Неужели так много успели? – Вот черт, **сколько раз тебе повторять**!.. Девяносто восемь процентов. [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий]

**Сколько тебе повторять** ― это бел-лет-рис-ти-ка! [Ирина Павская. (2006)]

― Неважно когда, важно как, Игорек, **сколько раз тебе повторять.** [Марианна Баконина. (2000)]

2) Не стоит менять структуру предложения, так как здесь, мне кажется,  **важно обозначить повтор**: **Не нАдо так делать, так делать нельзЯ**.  Вводное предложение при этом уходит на второй план речи.